# Placeholder не отображается в input

Tags: html, css

Вот часть кода, с которым у меня проблемы. Не понимаю, почему не отображается Placeholders. Дело не в браузере (Я открываю другой html там же и placeholders работает). В чем может быть косяк, пожалуйста, подскажите.

```
<form id="form" action="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts" class="contacts__form">
            <input name="Имя" type="text" placeholder="Имя*" data-validate-field="name"
              class="contacts__form-input form-name" autocomplete="off" id="name">
            <input name="tel" type="tel" class="contacts__form-input form-phone" placeholder="Телефон*"
              data-validate-field="tel" data-validate-rules="phone" autocomplete="off" id="tel">
            <button class="btn-reset contacts__form-btn" id="submit-btn">Заказать обратный звонок</button>
          </form>

enter image description hereHere is the part of my code which I have problems with. Can't understand why the Placeholders are not seen. It's not the problem of the browser (I open another html here and placeholders work). Please, hint what can be wrong?

<form id="form" action="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts" class="contacts__form">
            <input name="Имя" type="text" placeholder="Имя*" data-validate-field="name"
              class="contacts__form-input form-name" autocomplete="off" id="name">
            <input name="tel" type="tel" class="contacts__form-input form-phone" placeholder="Телефон*"
              data-validate-field="tel" data-validate-rules="phone" autocomplete="off" id="tel">
            <button class="btn-reset contacts__form-btn" id="submit-btn">Заказать обратный звонок</button>
          </form>
```

Head:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/flavicon.png" type="image/png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/simplebar@latest/dist/simplebar.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/choices.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/accordion.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/media.css">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/simplebar@latest/dist/simplebar.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/choices.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/dropdown.js"></script>
  <script src="js/scroll.js"></script>
  <script src="js/painters-buttons.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/just-validate@latest/dist/just-validate.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/inputmask.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=ваш API-ключ&lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/ymaps.js"></script>
```

Скрипты в конце body:

```
<script src="js/focus-visible.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/slider.js"></script>
  <script src="js/select.js"></script>
  <script src="js/accordion.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/accordion.js"></script>
  <script src="js/validation.js"></script>
  <script src="js/validation-rules.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```
.contacts__form-input {
  width: 270px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #333333;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.form-name, .form-phone {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: var(--dusty-gray-color);
}

::-moz-placeholder {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: var(--dusty-gray-color);
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: var(--dusty-gray-color);
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: var(--dusty-gray-color);
}

.contacts__form-btn {
  margin-right: 69px;
  padding: 12.5px 35px;
  padding-right: 36px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: var(--amethyst-color);
  border: 2px solid var(--amethyst-color);
  border-radius: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Помогла эта ссылка. Все работает теперь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18521929/multiple-styles-for-input-placeholder-text

Answer (score 0):

Если взять только html и css, то плейсхолдер будет нормально отображаться. Видимо, проблема в какой-то из многочисленных css- и js-библиотек, которые у Вас подключены. Попробуйте отключить все, а потом включать по одной и смотреть, в какой момент плейсхолдер перестанет отображаться.

```css
.contacts__form-input {
  width: 270px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #333333;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.form-name, .form-phone {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: var(--dusty-gray-color);
}

::-moz-placeholder {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: var(--dusty-gray-color);
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: var(--dusty-gray-color);
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: var(--dusty-gray-color);
}

.contacts__form-btn {
  margin-right: 69px;
  padding: 12.5px 35px;
  padding-right: 36px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: var(--amethyst-color);
  border: 2px solid var(--amethyst-color);
  border-radius: 100px;
}
```

```html
<form id="form" action="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts" class="contacts__form">
            <input name="Имя" type="text" placeholder="Имя*" data-validate-field="name"
              class="contacts__form-input form-name" autocomplete="off" id="name">
            <input name="tel" type="tel" class="contacts__form-input form-phone" placeholder="Телефон*"
              data-validate-field="tel" data-validate-rules="phone" autocomplete="off" id="tel">
            <button class="btn-reset contacts__form-btn" id="submit-btn">Заказать обратный звонок</button>
          </form>

<form id="form" action="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts" class="contacts__form">
            <input name="Имя" type="text" placeholder="Имя*" data-validate-field="name"
              class="contacts__form-input form-name" autocomplete="off" id="name">
            <input name="tel" type="tel" class="contacts__form-input form-phone" placeholder="Телефон*"
              data-validate-field="tel" data-validate-rules="phone" autocomplete="off" id="tel">
            <button class="btn-reset contacts__form-btn" id="submit-btn">Заказать обратный звонок</button>
          </form>
```

Comment: Отключила все библиотеки и скрипты. Плэйсхолдеры не появились....

Comment: @Nevereverstill, значит либо не всё отключили, либо кеш надо почистить, либо какой-то ещё код влияет (который Вы не привели). Здесь же всё работает:  я специально сделал воспроизводимый пример с Вашим кодом - можете нажать кнопку "Выполнить код" и убедиться, что все плейсхолдеры на месте.

Comment: У меня оказывается выше в коде был прописан еще один плэйсхолдер.

Answer (score 0):

У меня, оказывается, в коде выше был прописан еще один плэйсхолдер для поиска по сайту.

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
}

input:-moz-placeholder {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
}

input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
}
```